# How to handle xhr.js error gracefully using axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, error-handling, axios

```
 export const startLogin = (email, password) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('/admins/login', {email, password})
            if( response.status === 201 ) {
                dispatch(Login(response.data.token))
                return response
            }
        } catch(error) {
            if(error.response && error.response.status === 400) {
                console.log(error.response.data)
                return Promise.reject(error.response.data.error)
            } else if(error.request) {
                console.log('Request error: ', error.request)
            } else {
                console.log(error.response)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to handle 400 bad request error upon user login. I get the desired response error message from my nodejs server. but the problem is I am also getting a weird console error message that says:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/admins/login 400 (Bad Request) xhr.js:178
```

and i tried everything i could do, catching all the errors like above but it didnt work. what could be the problem here?

How can i  handle this console error gracefully? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: - This might be of help: https://www.intricatecloud.io/2020/03/how-to-handle-api-errors-in-your-web-app-using-axios/
  - Also, try looking into the `validateStatus` config in axios [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors)